# facing error while working with 'for' loop in python

Tags: python

While doing a question of printing table I faced a problem which I wasn't able to understand...

please explain:

```
x=input('enter a number btw 1-12')
if(not x.isdigit() and x>13 and x<0):
    print("value should be btw 1 to 12")
else:
    y=range(1,11)
    for i in y:
        print(x*i)**
```

result-(when x=2)

```
2
22
222
2222
22222
222222
2222222
22222222
222222222
2222222222
```

I don't know why I am getting a series instead of

```
2
4
6
8
10
12
.
.
.
.
20
```

Comment: `x` is a string and needs converting to an `int` if you want to compare it to `13` or `0`.

Comment: `x` is a string, not an integer, so `x>13 and x<0` won't work. You may try `x=int(input('enter a number btw 1-12'))`

Comment: `'2' * 4 == '2222'`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I read inputs as numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20449427/how-can-i-read-inputs-as-numbers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The input function in Python always takes the input as a string.

You need to convert it to an integer using `int()` or float using `float()` before adding it.

Like this:

```
else:
    x = int(x)
    y=range(1,11)
    for i in y:
        print(x*i)**
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify that you input is an int and not a string.
Also I would use the 'or' operator instead of 'and' in the if(x>13 or x<0):. Hope that helps!

```
x=int(input('enter a number btw 1-12'))

if(x>13 or x<0):
    print("value should be btw 1 to 12")

else:
    y=range(1,11)
    for i in y:
        print(x*i)
```